# Contribute Widget showing Placeholder on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

There are a few posts that report this error but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

Wordpress 4.9.4
Civi 4.7.27
http://radiowaterloo.ca/

I have a contribution widget in the Content Sidebar. On the home page, it displays "placeholder", similar to what others have reported. On any other page on the site, it displays as expected.

JSON output is also the same whether I look at the homepage or another page:

var jsondata3 = {"currencySymbol":"$","is_error":false,"is_active":true,"title":"FRIENDS OF CKMS FUNDING DRIVE 2018","logo":null,"button_title":"Contribute Now!","about":"

CKMS NEEDS YOUR HELP!</strong></big></p>\r\n\r\n

The radio station is entirely run by volunteers and does not receive any ongoing funding from government or universities. The majority of our operations are funded by fees paid by the on-air hosts and donations from listeners like you!</big></p>","num_donors":"2 Donors","money_raised":"Raised $ 30.00 of $ 2,500.00","campaign_start":"Campaign ends on March 24th, 2018","money_target":2500,"money_raised_percentage":"1%","money_target_display":"$ 2,500.00","money_low":0,"home_url":"Learn more.</a>","homepage_link":null,"colors":{"title":"#000000","button":"#FFFFFF","bar":"#2786C2","main_text":"#000000","main":"#33FFF6","main_bg":"#FFFF00","bg":"#96C0E7","about_link":"#556C82"}};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a Javascript error on your homepage that isn't present on other pages:

`Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function at jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=4.9.4`

If you fix this, I expect the widget will work.